# How to increment numbers automatically after the insert of a new row?

Tags: excel, vba

In my data table I am trying to insert a new row whenever a new information is added. 
Each row has a unique index, for example in the first column, I have some work domains such as Pilotage, in the second column I have sub domains of the domain for example for Pilotage I have Quality, the index is Pil_01. Each sub domain has its own products, when I add a product in position 15, I want that the indexes below line 15 that belong to the domain pilotage to be incremented by 1

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()    
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim dom As String
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newrow As ListRow

    ' domain is the name of the comobox in which the user will choose the domain and subdomain the name of the comobox in which the user will choose the sub domain\ domsubdomain is a column in my table which has the 3 first letters of the domain concatenated with the subdomain
    dom = Left(domain, 3) & subdomain
    position = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dom, Sheets("Data").Range("domsubdomain"), 0)

    ' this is the code allowing me to insert a new row and add some data into it
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Referentiel")
    Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add(position + 1)

    With newrow
        .Range(2) = subdomain
        .Range(3) = Produit
        .Range(4) = Procedure
    If Procedure <> "" Then
        count = 1
        .Range(5) = Processus
    End If


    ' The for loop will allow me to go through all data in that column starting from the new row's position and increment the cells by one. It stops when meeting a new domain
    For i = position To 1000
        If dom = Sheets("Data").Range("domsubdomain").Cells(i, 25).Value Then
            chaine = Sheets("Data").Range("domsubdomain").Cells(i, 24).Value
            chaine = chaine + 1
            Sheets("Data").Range("domsubdomain").Cells(i, 24).Value = chaine
        Else
            MsgBox "Exit"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i  
End Sub
```

with this code I have the message exit instead of going through the code below

Comment: That means your `If` statement is not `True`. Debug your code, go through it step by step using F8 and check the value of `dom` and `Sheets("Data").Range("domsubdomain").Cells(i, 25).Value` • Actually `subpo` is not declared and therefore `0` so it should error at `Cells(i, 25)` • Make sure you use `Option Explicit` as first line in your code. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ nothing comes up. For subpro it was a mistake I forgot to change it to position

Comment: in your `CommandButton2_Click` write as first line `Stop`. Then click your button. If it stops at `Stop` with a yellow line start pressing F8 it goes through your code then step by step. If it comes to your `If` statement check the values.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it came to dom value 1st but I put a msgbox to make sure it comes out as I want and it does.

Comment: and what is the result of it? and what is the result of `Sheets("Data").Range("domsubdomain").Cells(i, 25).Value`? If you expect us to help we need much more details than *"it does"*.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it concatenates the 3 letters of the domain with the sub domain

Comment: Sorry you need to tell the **exact** result (value) of both expressions (that I asked in my comments before). And you need to answer the questions. We cannot help you if you don't provide the information we ask for. Reading [mcve] might also help to improve your question.